# Table with multicolumn!

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I would like your help to build the following table: My question is on the first line where the cells containing the BIAS and RMSE names are bigger than the cells of the lines below. Summing up the first line with 3 columns with the following lines are 5 columns. Thank you very much.[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To create these columns simply use

```
\multicolumn{2}{c}{<content of cell>}
```

This cell will span `2` columns and be `c`entred horizontally.

Then proceed as usual.

Here's a complete example, based on the content which [Wayne Tsai](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323278/) typed for you.

The code follows recommended guidelines, which eschew the use of vertical lines in tables; use heavier rules for top and bottom; minimise additional rules within the table body; increase spacing around rules; and align numerical values appropriately.

I use `booktabs` for the improved rules and spacing. Please read the documentation for advice on typesetting tables.

I use `siunitx` to align the content of the cells on the `,` which I assume to be the decimal marker.

These recommendations are intended to make tabular material easier to read and to produce publication-quality results.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{%
  output-decimal-marker={,},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c*{4}{S}}
  \toprule
  \bfseries Index &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries BIAS}  &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries RMSE} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){1-5}
  \bfseries Models &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries AGCM} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries CGCM} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries AGCM} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries CGCM} \\
  \midrule
  SACZ-2005 & -1,7 & -2,0 & 7,0  & 5,9 \\
  SACZ-2006 & -0,6 & -0,7 & 4,3  & 4,1 \\
  SACZ-2007 & 1,6  & 2,0  & 5,4  & 5,6 \\
  SACZ-2008 & -1,4 & -2,8 & 10,7 & 9,2 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: complete example]

Answer (score 4):

Use `\multicolumn`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
Index &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{BIAS}  &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{RMSE} \\
\hline
Models &  AGCM & CGCM & AGCM & CGCM \\
\hline
SACZ-2005 & $-1,7$ & $-2,0$ & 7,0 & 5,9 \\
\hline
SACZ-2006 & $-0,6$ & $-0,7$ & 4,3 & 4,1 \\
\hline
SACZ-2007 & 1,6    & 2,0    & 5,4 & 5,6 \\
\hline
SACZ-2008 & $-1,4$ & $-2,8$ & 10,7 & 9,2 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you forcing a line break and adding 4mm of space after the table? `\\ ` should only be used to break lines in very specific contexts: *inside* `tabular` and `array` environments, for example. Otherwise, you get lots of bad box warnings. And you don't need the AMS packages here, either. Why do you think the OP needs support for commutative diagrams?

Comment: I hope you don't mind. I edited this so I could upvote it in good conscience ;).

Comment: @cfr Actually, I didn't notice the 4mm of space initially. This solution code is modified from other documents of mine. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: That explains the packages. But you shouldn't be using `\\ ` either!

Comment: @cfr This is what I want to ask also (however out of range of this question): how would I add more space after the table, without `\\ `?

Comment: `\vspace{}` or `\vspace*{}`? Or you can say, e.g. `\bigskip` or `\medskip` or `\smallskip` if you are then starting a new paragraph.

Comment: @cfr Thanks! It does work and there is no longer bad box warnings.